# React, Binding input values

Tags: javascript, input, data-binding, reactjs

I'm having some problems with binding the value of an input, I have done it on another component of my app and it worked fine, but somehow I can't get it works on another component. I'm only getting the first letter and not the whole text

This is my component

```
class Post extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      post: this.props.data,
      comment: ''
    }
    Post.context = this;
  }
render() {
<input type="text" value={this.state.comment} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="Write a comment..." />
      <button className="button comments" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null,this.state.post.id)}></button>
}
 handleChange(e) {
    Post.context.setState({comment: e.target.value});
}
}
```

I also tried to use an example from React website but it got the same result:

```
 render() {
     var valueLink = {
      value: this.state.comment,
      requestChange: this.handleChange
    };
 render() {
    <input type="text" valueLink={valueLink} placeholder="Write a comment..." />
          <button className="button comments" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(null,this.state.post.id)}></button>
    }
     handleChange(newValue) {
        Post.context.setState({comment: newValue});
    }
    }
```

Does someone have idea, why this is happening?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You must wrap `input` and `button` in *root* element (for example div)., component can have only one root element.

You can use `.bind` like in my example, and avoid using `Post.context = this;`

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      post: this.props.data,
      comment: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.comment} 
        onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } 
        placeholder="Write a comment..." />

      <button 
        className="button comments" 
        onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.post.id)}>Button</button>
    </div>
    }

  handleClick(postId, e) {
    console.log( postId );
    console.log( this.state.comment );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ comment: e.target.value });
  }
}
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/122913/)

**Note:** React 16.* contains the new feature - [**`Fragments`**](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html), which allows skipping additional root element.

```
render() {
  return (
    <>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.comment} 
        onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } 
        placeholder="Write a comment..."
      />

      <button 
        className="button comments" 
        onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.post.id)}
      >
        Button<
      /button>
    </>
  )
}
```