# react auto binding on click is automatic for this

Tags: reactjs

I find contradictions in some sites about react autobindig, example:

first link do manual autobind
[React, Binding input values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037777/react-binding-input-values)

```
class Post extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      post: this.props.data,
      comment: ''
    };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input 
        type="text" 
        value={this.state.comment} 
        onChange={ this.handleChange.bind(this) } 
        placeholder="Write a comment..." />

      <button 
        className="button comments" 
        onClick={ this.handleClick.bind(this, this.state.post.id)}>Button</button>
    </div>
    }

  handleClick(postId, e) {
    console.log( postId );
    console.log( this.state.comment );
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ comment: e.target.value });
  }
}
```

second link do automatic
http://buildwithreact.com/tutorial/state

on the last link:

```
var CowClicker = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      clicks: 0
    };
  },

  onCowClick: function(evt) {
    this.setState({
      clicks: this.state.clicks + 1
    });
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Clicks: {this.state.clicks}</div>
        <img
          src="http://s3.bypaulshen.com/buildwithreact/cow.png"
          onClick={this.onCowClick}
          className="cow"
        />
        <p>Click the cow</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <CowClicker />,
  document.getElementById('container')
```

"NOTE: AUTOBINDING
You may be surprised that we don't need to pass the callback as this.onCowClick.bind(this). (If not, read this). This is because React autobinds methods on the component instance for performance reasons. Read more here."

React do autobinding? if the answer is 'yes', sometimes you need to bind manually in some case with onclick ??

Comment: react do autobinding if you're using createClass. You don't need to do it manually.

Comment: thanks, I've updated my answer, first link with code do, manual, why ? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React v0.13, es6 classes is introduced and there is no auto-bind.
auto bind is introduced in React v0.4.

If you have some old project using React with version earlier than v0.4, there is no auto-bind.

I was confused by the learning material too and I have create a [post](https://medium.com/@sundaykuloksun/tricky-autobinding-in-react-bc7b4a70ce85) to talk about this.

Comment: nice blog i see clearer, i prefer ES6, did you try typescript ? i'd like to code all in typescript, but i'm not sure

Comment: I haven't try typescript, but I believe it also work. As typescript is an extension of javascript, it does not change the behaviour defined by js

Answer (score 0):

As user @havenchyk explained,

> Using React.createClass will automatically bind this values correctly for us, but changes when using ES6 classes affect this. With ES6 classes this is slightly different, properties of the class do not automatically bind to the React class instance.

Source: https://toddmotto.com/react-create-class-versus-component/

- In your first example, they are using the ES6 approach. In the second, they are using the traditional

Answer (score 0):

when you use `React.createClass` react do binding for you.
if you are using es6 class syntax react no more do binding for you.
it means you should manually do `.bind(this)`.

but you can use fat arrow functions which don't define their own `this` value, instead they are bound to the **lexical this** of their current context.

check it out http://codepen.io/dagman/pen/wzgvja

```
class Button extends React.Component {
    handleClick = () => {
        alert('Hello World');
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <button onClick={this.handleClick}>button</button>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Button />,
    document.getElementById('mount-node')
);
```

Comment: React.createClass bind automatically, but  React.Component  not, it's React.createClass old way ? I must not use it ? thanks

Comment: from the official docs:  "Our eventual goal is for ES6 classes to replace React.createClass completely, but until we have a replacement for current mixin use cases and support for class property initializers in the language, we don't plan to deprecate React.createClass." what does mean?

Comment: i don't think  `React.createClass` old way cos you can use es6 cool stuff with it too. I think it is just matter of preference.