# JSX Text Input doesn't work if it has an onChange property (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input, onchange

I'm having an issue where any text input that has an onChange property
will not let me type in it.
I still do have a milisecond of time that I can type something in it,
but I can barely type one letter at a time if I really try.

The way I usually solved this problem was to get the value of the input once using document.getElementById().value, instead of having a function that does it automatically.

Basically I did this

```js
<input id="something" type="text" />
<button onClick={() => doSomething(document.getElementById("something").value)}>Click Me!</button>
```

instead of this,

```js
<input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
<button onClick={() => doSomething(value)}>Click Me!</button>
```

but now I need to do some real time updates so I need this method.

Comment: `onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}` makes no sense, you're updating the input with it's current value? I think you instead need to bind the value with your state, as outlined [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React, Binding input values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34037777/979052)

Comment: @Lissy93 I just gave an example, and that value can be used for something else in the code. If I have a realtime display, I'm setting the value for the input AND for the display.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that somehow the fix was to just make on giant React component that stores all the code instead of smaller, organized components.